# Help to undertand the meaning of bounded family of surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

At this link [article](http://math1.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/ac.pdf)  there is the Beauville's article that i'm reading for my thesis. For me it is not clear what the author means when he uses the term "bounded family" at page 124 after Theorem 1.6. Can someone help me to understand better the meaning of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually after the statement of Proposition 1.7 it explains exactly what is meant ("Cela signifie..."): there is a variety $S$ and a morphism $X \rightarrow S$ such that each surface in the class under discussion is isomorphic to one of the fibres $X_s$. Just to emphasise, _bounded_ refers to the fact that the "parameter space" $S$ for these surface is of _finite type_, rather than being, say, some scheme with infinitely many components.

Comment: My theacher says that this concept is related with this theorem: if we fix two numerical invariant $K^2$ and $\chi$ then there exist a quasi projective moduli space of the canonical model of surfaces of general type with invariany $K^2$ and $\chi$. So in this quasi projective space is it true that i get a finite number of surfaces with the same numerical invariant that are my families?

Comment: I don't really understand your last question; in particular, a family does not consist of a single surface or a finite number of surfaces, but rather one surface for each point in the parameter space.

Comment: Anyway, I think it is best for you to ask your teacher directly about these things. There are only so many questions that can be answered on this website.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh is the morphis in your first comment equal to the application $m$ at page 233 of this article ? (http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/pdf/?PPN=GDZPPN002093766) you have to download: Global Moduli for Surfaces of General Type. I think yes. So is the fiber $X_s$ under the application $m$ in the set $S$ using the notations of the article? i think that my problem is to understand in the article what is the meaning of quasi projective moduli space for surfaces of general type

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "limitée" means bounded. It rather means limited to a certain set defined by some properties of the members.

Look at this sentence from the article:

"Nous allons maintenant montrer qu'il existe effectivement des families **non
limitées de surfaces de type général** dont le systeme canonique est composé d'un
pinceau de courbes de genre 2 ou 3."

Comment: _Bounded family_ is a technical term (not the same as the usual meaning of bounded) with a precise meaning in algebraic geometry, and _famille limit\'ee_ is the French translation of that term.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: I do believe what you are saying. But then, how come that I could not find the term in the French Wiki? (This is not a provocation, I am really curious.)

Comment: Wikipedia (even in English) has lots of gaps. This is a specialised technical term, that is not even defined in standard algebraic geometry books such as Hartshorne.